# Extract specific values from xml format to a comma separated value format (csv) with Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, csv, xml

I need to extract specific values from XML format to a comma-separated value format (CSV) with Notepad++

The XML source file looks like:[source file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18AaiIRceh1dn3FV9xlnwdLJN7WfcaTD3/view?usp=sharing)

```
  GRID id="301019" x="**328.217224**" y="**543.844177**" z="**0.000000**" rx="**0.000000** **-1.000000 0.000000**" ry="**1.000000 0.000000 0.000000**" rz="**0.000000 0.000000 1.000000**"/

  GRID id="303001" x="328.217224" y="518.844177" z="0.000000" rx="0.000000 -1.000000 0.000000" ry="1.000000 0.000000 0.000000" rz="0.000000 0.000000 1.000000"/

  GRID id="303002" x="328.217224" y="493.844177" z="0.000000" rx="0.000000 -1.000000 0.000000" ry="1.000000 0.000000 0.000000" rz="0.000000 0.000000 1.000000"/

  GRID id="303003" x="328.217224" y="468.844177" z="0.000000" rx="0.000000 -1.000000 0.000000" ry="1.000000 0.000000 0.000000" rz="0.000000 0.000000 1.000000"/

  GRID id="301020" x="328.217224" y="443.844177" z="0.000000" rx="0.000000 -1.000000 0.000000" ry="1.000000 0.000000 0.000000" rz="0.000000 0.000000 1.000000"/
```

12 coordinates per grid need to be extracted in the following form:
X,Y,Z,xx,xy,xz,zx,yy,yz,zx,zy,zz

So the sample above should result in:

```
328.217224,543.844177,0.000000,0.000000,-1.000000,0.000000,1.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,1.000000
328.217224,518.844177,0.000000,0.000000,-1.000000,0.000000,1.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,1.000000
328.217224,493.844177,0.000000,0.000000,-1.000000,0.000000,1.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,1.000000
328.217224,468.844177,0.000000,0.000000,-1.000000,0.000000,1.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,1.000000
328.217224,443.844177,0.000000,0.000000,-1.000000,0.000000,1.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,1.000000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the great flatten xml2 Linux utility (https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/xml2/2csv.1) and starting from your xml source, run

```
xml2 <  input.xml | 2csv GRID @id @x @y @z @rx @ry @rz
```

to obtain

```
+--------+------------+------------+----------+-----------------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+
| 301019 | 328.217224 | 543.844177 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 -1.000000 0.000000 | 1.000000 0.000000 0.000000 | 0.000000 0.000000 1.000000 |
| 303001 | 328.217224 | 518.844177 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 -1.000000 0.000000 | 1.000000 0.000000 0.000000 | 0.000000 0.000000 1.000000 |
| 303002 | 328.217224 | 493.844177 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 -1.000000 0.000000 | 1.000000 0.000000 0.000000 | 0.000000 0.000000 1.000000 |
| 303003 | 328.217224 | 468.844177 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 -1.000000 0.000000 | 1.000000 0.000000 0.000000 | 0.000000 0.000000 1.000000 |
| 301020 | 328.217224 | 443.844177 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 -1.000000 0.000000 | 1.000000 0.000000 0.000000 | 0.000000 0.000000 1.000000 |
+--------+------------+------------+----------+-----------------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+
```

Then you can split the last 3 columns by space in a lot of way

In notepad there is not a simple way to do it, because XML is a complex file.
You can run Linux utility also in Windows

Comment: Thanks for your response. This might be the solution I am looking for, but I do not know how to run this utility in Windows.

Comment: @IvanKrajnc you could enable WSL and install Ubuntu. You will have a Linux shell inside windows, in which you can install xml2 https://www.dataquest.io/blog/tutorial-install-linux-on-windows-wsl/

Comment: Thanks again for being helpful.